# active class based on click in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

is this possible to add active class based on click .
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7kmxa8x/1/)

```
<button class="btn btn-twitter btn-left-icon" ng-class="{'active' : install}" type="button" ng-click="liveHint('install')">
    نصب جدید
</button>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-twitter btn-left-icon" ng-class="{'active' :add}" ng-click="liveHint('add')">
    ادغام
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-twitter btn-left-icon" ng-class="{'active' :add}" ng-click="liveHint('add')">
    تفکیک

</button>
```

Comment: do you want to make button or buttons group active with click?

Comment: no one button for one click

Comment: your question is not clear. do you want other button disabled. Can you give your full scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to update your buttons to the following:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-twitter btn-left-icon" ng-class="{'active' :add}" ng-click="add = true">
    ادغام
    <span class=" fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true">
    </span>
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-twitter btn-left-icon" ng-class="{'active' :add}" ng-click="add = true">
    تفکیک
    <span class=" fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true">
    </span>
</button>
```

When $scope.add is true it will apply the active class to your elements that have

```
ng-class="{'active':add}"
```

or

in your liveHint function set $scope.add equal to true like this:

```
angular.module("CheckAllModule", [])
.controller("checkboxController", function checkboxController($scope) {
    $scope.add = false;
    $scope.install = false;

    $scope.liveHint = function (mode) {
    if (mode == 'add')
    {
        $scope.add = !$scope.add;
    }
        else if (mode == 'install')
        {
            $scope.install = !$scope.install;
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: You can set it in the view or controller.  You probably want to do it in the controller by modifying your liveHint function if you need to do other logic when the buttons are clicked.